# Subversion 1.6 + SASL : Only works with plaintext 'userPassword'?

Tags: svn, encryption, sasl

I'm attempting to setup `svnserve` with SASL support on my Slackware 13.1 server and after some trial and error I'm able to get it to work with the configuration listed below:

#### svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
realm = myrepo

[sasl]
use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 128
max-encryption = 256
```

#### /etc/sasl2/svn.conf

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
sasldb_path: /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb
mech_list: DIGEST-MD5
```

#### sasldb users

```
$ sasldblistusers2 -f /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb
test@myrepo: cmusaslsecretOTP
test@myrepo: userPassword
```

You'll notice that the output of `sasldblistusers2` shows my *test* user as having both an encrypted *cmusaslsecretOTP* password as well as a **plain text** *userPassword* passwd. i.e., if I were to run `strings /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb` I would see the *test* users' password in plaintext.  These two password entries were created with the following subversion book recommended command:

```
saslpasswd2 -c -f /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb -u myrepo test
```

After reading `man saslpasswd2` I see the following option:

> **-n**     Don't set the plaintext userPassword property for the user. 
>   Only mechanism-specific secrets will
>   be set (e.g. OTP, SRP)

This is exactly what I want to do, suppress the plain text password and only use the mechanism-specific secret (OTP in my case).  So I clear out `/etc/sasl2/my_sasldb` and rerun `saslpasswd2` as:

```
saslpasswd2 -n -c -f /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb -u myrepo test
```

I then follow it up with a `sasldblistusers2` and I see:

```
$ sasldblistusers2 -f /etc/sasl2/my_sasldb
test@myrepo: cmusaslsecretOTP
```

***Perfect!*** I think, now I have only encrypted passwords.... only neither the Linux `svn` client nor the Windows `TortoiseSVN` client can connect to my repo anymore.  They both present me with the user/pass challenge but that's as far as I get.

---

#### TLDR

So, what is the point of SVN supporting SASL if my sasldb **must** store its passwords in plaintext to work?

Comment: Anything interesting under /var/log/ files? Disabling plaintext SHOULD be a completely normal thing to do.

Comment: @Janne I had `svnserve` run with `--daemon --foreground` and I don't see any output in that screen.  I'll tail `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog` to see if I get anything useful out of that.

Comment: @Janne The only output I see is in `/var/log/debug` when I connect from the Linux `svn` client.  Without `userPasswd` I only see `svn: DIGEST-MD5 client step 2`, however *with* `userPasswd` I see both that and `svn: DIGEST-MD5 client step 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly an answer but I'd like to point out that there are some sources that say explicitely that DIGEST-MD5 does not (and will never) support hashed passwords because it needs the plaintext password to do the challenge/response, like:

- http://cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-sasl/2.1.25/sysadmin.php
- http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html#DIGEST-MD5

Other sources say otherwise:

- [OpenLDAP, SASL and non-cleartext password storage](https://serverfault.com/questions/312740/openldap-sasl-and-non-cleartext-password-storage)
- [SASL + postfixadmin - SMTP authentication with hashed password](https://serverfault.com/questions/232156/sasl-postfixadmin-smtp-authentication-with-hashed-password)